# How to compare two "numbers" with multiple dots?

Tags: c#

I have an unordered list that can look something like this:

1

2.2

1.1.1

3

When i sort the list, 1.1.1 becomes greater than 3 and 2.2, and 2.2 becomes greater than 3.

This is because Double.Parse removes the dots and makes it a whole number.

This is the method i use to sort with:

```
public class CompareCategory: IComparer<Category>
{
    public int Compare(Category c1, Category c2)
    {
        Double cat1 = Double.Parse(c1.prefix);
        Double cat2 = Double.Parse(c2.prefix);

        if (cat1 > cat2)
            return 1;
        else if (cat1 < cat2)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to compare they as strings?

Comment: Post the Category class, and double.parse does not work the why you think

Comment: A regular string comparsion solved the problem. Thanks. Please post an answer.

Comment: I think you will find that the string comparison will not work for all cases.

Comment: @iandotkelly is correct: consider the question of how 1.1, 1.10 and 1.2 should sort.  Do you have any bounds on the problem? For example, do you know that every section will always be a number less than two billion, or do you have to handle arbitrarily large strings of this form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are these version #s by chance? Can you use [the `Version` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx)?  It sorts each part as you seem to want, although it only works up to 4 parts.  I would not recommend parsing into a numeric value like you are doing.

It has an `IComparable` interface. Assuming your inputs are strings, here's a sample:

```
public class CompareCategory: IComparer<Category>
{
    public int Compare(Category c1, Category c2)
    {
        var cat1 = new Version(c1.prefix);
        var cat2 = new Version(c2.prefix);

        if (cat1 > cat2)
            return 1;
        else if (cat1 < cat2)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

If you need something with more than 4 "parts", I think I would create a comparer which split the strings at the dots, and then parse each element as an integer and compare them numerically.   Make sure to consider cases like 1.002.3 and 1.3.3 (what do you want the sort order to be?).

**Update**, here is a sample of what I mean.  Lightly tested:

```
    public class CategoryComparer : Comparer<Category>
    {
        public override int Compare(Category x, Category y)
        {
            var xParts = x.prefix.Split(new[] { '.' });
            var yParts = y.prefix.Split(new[] { '.' });

            int index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                bool xHasValue = xParts.Length > index;
                bool yHasValue = yParts.Length > index;
                if (xHasValue && !yHasValue)
                    return 1;   // x bigger
                if (!xHasValue && yHasValue)
                    return -1;  // y bigger
                if (!xHasValue && !yHasValue)
                    return 0;   // no more values -- same
                var xValue = decimal.Parse("." + xParts[index]);
                var yValue = decimal.Parse("." + yParts[index]);
                if (xValue > yValue)
                    return 1;   // x bigger
                if (xValue < yValue)
                    return -1;  // y bigger
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category { prefix = "1" },
            new Category { prefix = "2.2" },
            new Category { prefix = "1.1.1" },
            new Category { prefix = "1.1.1" },
            new Category { prefix = "1.001.1" },
            new Category { prefix = "3" },
        };

        categories.Sort(new CategoryComparer());
        foreach (var category in categories)
            Console.WriteLine(category.prefix);
    }
```

Output:

```
1
1.001.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
2.2
3
```

Comment: Great answer.  Does the Version class cope with an unlimited number of levels to your version?

Comment: No, the version class is restricted to 4 parts.

Comment: Still, I would use it in preference to my solution if it were limited to 4 parts.  Much less work.

Comment: I get a Version string portion was too short or too long error, with Version. Could you perhaps show an example with the Split ?

Comment: Just updated, I didn't test it too much -- I treated each part as a value to the right of a decimal point so "001" would be less than "1".  Hopefully that is what you want.

Comment: Looks great! Only thing is that i get this exception: Input string was not in a correct format. Index = 0 and xParts[0] = 1, var xValue = decimal.Parse("." + xParts[index]); - Thanks for trying btw

Comment: Can you send me the input values you are using?  The test program above works for me, does it work for you?  You might need to change the decimal.Parse to decimal.TryParse to handle non-numeric values...

Comment: I am using the ones that you have provided in your sample :/ if i remove "." from decimal.Parse it works, but doesnt give the correct output: 1,
1.1.1,
,1.001.1
,1.1.1
,2.2
,3

Comment: That is strange -- I just double-checked with a new project & it works here.  How about changing it to "0." instead of "."?  What version of .NET are you using?  (I am using VS2010, 4.0)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4809/discussion-between-johnd-and-kenci)

Comment: Do you get an exception when you write: var hej = decimal.Parse(".1"); ?

Comment: var hej = decimal.Parse(".1");  succeeds on my machine (hej = 0.1)

Comment: CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var xValue = decimal.Parse("." + xParts[index], culture);
var yValue = decimal.Parse("." + yParts[index], culture); 
fixes the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CodeComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xParts = x.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        var yParts = y.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        var partsLength = Math.Max(xParts.Length, yParts.Length);
        if (partsLength > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < partsLength; i++)
            {
                if (xParts.Length <= i) return -1;// 4.2 < 4.2.x
                if (yParts.Length <= i) return 1;

                var xPart = xParts[i];
                var yPart = yParts[i];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xPart)) xPart = "0";// 5..2->5.0.2
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yPart)) yPart = "0";

                if (!int.TryParse(xPart, out var xInt) || !int.TryParse(yPart, out var yInt))
                {
                    // 3.a.45 compare part as string
                    var abcCompare = xPart.CompareTo(yPart);
                    if (abcCompare != 0)
                        return abcCompare;
                    continue;
                }

                if (xInt != yInt) return xInt < yInt ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        // compare as string
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just string compare it?

Comment: String will not handle numbers correct in some cases. For examlpe, if given this set of strings 1, 12, 3, 4, and you order by ascending, you will get back [1, 12, 3, 4] because it sees the first two elements as starting with 1 and then orders by the second character, which is 2 for '12'. then it goes on to the 3 and 4.

Comment: You're right... This calls for a String.Split then compare, or the Version thing as @JohnD mentioned.

Comment: Well, a string split, convert to ints, and then compare. In the end, I think the version answer is the more concise one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that Double.Parse doesn't throw an exception with those numbers with more than one decimal place.

You really need to write some rules about how to compare these strings.

I would split the strings using String.Split() on the dot character, then iterate through the two lists created and as soon as one of the levels contained a lower or higher number than the other, or if you ran out of items in one of the lists then you wold return 1 or -1 as appropriate.  If you get to the end of both lists in the same iteration of the loop then they are the same and return 0.

I would write the code but I don't have VS in front of me.