# How to sort multiple decimal numbers in a list

Tags: c#

I want to sort multi decimal numbers (1.1, 1.2, etc.).
I have a set of numbers:

```
1.100
1
1.33
1.33.1
1.2
1.05
1.05.1.1
```

And I want it to become:

```
1
1.05
1.05.1.1
1.2
1.33
1.33.1
1.100
```

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    act.Add("1.100");
    act.Add("1.1"); 
    act.Add("1.33");    
    act.Add("1.33.1"); 
    act.Add("1.2");   
    act.Add("1.05"); 
    act.Add("1.05.1.1");
    act.Sort();

    for (int i = 0; i < act.Count; i++)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(act[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: please see this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056116/how-to-compare-two-numbers-with-multiple-dots) It may help you